# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sounds'

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python. I've been reading over the docs and just got to section [6.4](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) about packages and thought I'd test out the different scenarios and importing methods.

I created a simple project with this structure:

```py
importTest/
    __init__.py
    effects/
        __init__.py
        explosions.py
    sounds/
        __init__.py
        bird.py
```

I've opened the python interpreter, from the parent dir of `importTest`, in my terminal and ran:
`import importTest.sounds.bird` but got the error referenced in the title.

I've tried importing the dependencies in each `__init__.py` file, and just leaving the file blank, but for some reason I can't seem to get this to work. Based on the docs it seems like this is the way to structure a package with sub-packages. If anyone notices I'm not doing something glaringly obvious, let me know. I'd appreciate any assistance, thanks!

Comment: `effects` imports perfectly fine though?

Comment: @TMartin it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python import paths are always relative to the directory where the interpreter runs, which in this case is `importTest`. So if you want to import `sounds/bird.py` under it, you should simply do:

```
from sounds import bird
```

Comment: So i started the interpreter from the dir one level up from `importTest`. I was trying to do `import importTest.sounds.bird` but got that sounds is not a module.

Comment: I see. If you run the interpreter from the directory one level up from `importTest` then what you do should work. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/UnfortunateWholeShell

Comment: Weird, I cleared out all the code inside my `__init__` files and it worked. But I do have a question for you, i ran this: `import importTest.sounds` and then tried to access `importTest.sounds.bird.chirp()` and got `AttributeError: module 'importTest.sounds' has no attribute 'bird'` is that normal? Do i need to import `bird` into `sounds`' `__init__.py` file?

Comment: You should not have to do that. Please see the updated demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/UnfortunateWholeShell

Comment: Oops just realized you said you only did `import importTest.sounds` rather than `import importTest.sounds.bird`, in which case you do need to `import bird` into the `__init__.py` file of `sounds`.

Comment: Sorry about the constant noob questions I'm flinging at you, but I tried it: https://repl.it/@ehutchllew/UnfortunateWholeShell -- I'm getting that error, but not sure if this is just bad practice, and I need to be explicit in the imports or what.

Comment: Oops I misspelled `__init__.py` as `__Init__.py` in the file under `sounds`. That's why. Also you need to use `from . import bird` instead of just `import bird` in Python 3. Please check the updated demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/UnfortunateWholeShell-1

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton! Is the reason for the relative import because when `importTest` goes down the tree and sees `import bird` it's trying to access it from its own directory, like `importTest -> bird` rather than going `importTest -> sounds -> bird`?

Comment: You're welcome. The reason for the relative import is because Python 3 no longer supports implicit relative import, which used to be OK in Python 2, to avoid accidentally colliding with modules of the same names imported by other built-in modules.

Comment: Otherwise when it sees `import bird`, it will try to import it from the interpreter's working directory. That is, `parent_dir -> bird` rather than `parent_dir -> importTest -> bird` or `parent_dir -> importTest -> sounds -> bird`.